# Instagram API returning square only (cropped) images

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

1 year ago Instagram migrated the API to support landscape and portrait formats.

Looks like last week the api is returning a cropped square image.

Example: https://www.instagram.com/p/BHLY4N0jMfA/ (the image is not square)

Api endpoint (https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/igapitest/media/recent) returns cropped square image:

```
...
images: {
    low_resolution: {
        url: "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/c224.0.631.631/13556933_1110271362362401_1093314529_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTI4MjIyNzkzNTE2NDI4NjkxMg%3D%3D.2.c",
        width: 320,
        height: 320
    },
    thumbnail: {
        url: "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c224.0.631.631/13556933_1110271362362401_1093314529_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTI4MjIyNzkzNTE2NDI4NjkxMg%3D%3D.2.c",
        width: 150,
        height: 150
    },
    standard_resolution: {
        url: "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s480x480/e35/c224.0.631.631/13556933_1110271362362401_1093314529_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTI4MjIyNzkzNTE2NDI4NjkxMg%3D%3D.2.c",
        width: 480,
        height: 480
    }
},
...
```

Even if you try the media endpoint (https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/1282227935164286912_189136266) it returns cropped square images again.

Noticed that images used by the web Instagram comes from another cdn than the api returns.

Looks a bug in Instagram API? Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the option for "Non-square images" in your API settings.

I checked the same media using my API, I get landscape images.

The image URL is same except I dont have `c224.0.631.631/` in my API response's URLs, you can remove that from your URLs and you will get non-cropped images. But check your API settings.

Comment: I was receiving non-square images correctly... As the message says and the api behaviour, we should not receive cropped square images anymore. So looks like Instagram rolled back the feature? Anyway, the "Non-square images" flag on my client is not checked and i can't even update because i receive an error on their dashboard when updating: https://www.dropbox.com/s/048c1o6hkjro54b/Screenshot%202016-10-31%2016.35.59.jpg?dl=0 Of course all fields are ok.. my app is reviewed and in live mode.

Comment: I can check the flag for a sandbox mode app, but not for the live one...

Comment: not sure then, my client has "non-square media" checked

Comment: Instagram used to allow urls like http://whatever/foo and this is not allowed anymore. That's why i was receiving the error. After updating to http://local.whatever/foo the form went ok and i checked the "non-square images" flag. Now the API is responding correctly. Thanks