# Instagram API non-square images not being returned for $data->images->standard_resolution

Tags: php, regex, api, instagram, pcre

API URL:
api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=kablenghe

I'm trying to figure out a way to take the image URL for a standard_resolution image, but Instagram keeps serving up the cropped images.

Cropped Image URL:

scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s480x480/e35/c236.0.607.607/14474173_314142642294695_7071485231332589568_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=blah

Non-cropped Image URL:

scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s480x480/e35/14474173_314142642294695_7071485231332589568_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=splerf

So I need to removed the portion: "/c236.0.607.607" which is what Instagram uses to position and size the image crop.  Several people are asking this question, but I'm not finding anyone who's found the answer to this irritating little Instagram API issue with cropped images and non-square media.

Comment: [`preg_replace('~/c\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,4}){3}/~', '/', $url)`](https://regex101.com/r/ZT8vZo/3)

Comment: Can you provide a general pattern for the `c236.0.607.607` part? Does it always start with `c`, which numbers are recurring and which are not? If you don't know then at least provide more examples.

Comment: @Croutonix yes the section will always start with a /c and always has 4 period-separated numbers.  I may have solved the issue with my answer below, but if there is anyway to improve it I'd love your input!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried: \/c\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,4}){3} and got it to work with the escaped slash at the start and removing the slash on the end.

Comment: If you use `~` as a regex delimiter, you would not have to escape the slash in the pattern. You'd better use both leading and trailing slash, since otherwise, you may match a substring, not the whole URL part.

Comment: What's your standard_resolution for this endpoint? https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/igapitest/media/recent

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I think I may have actually figured it out.  Here's what I have:

```
// The standard_resolution URL from Instagram API Response
$full_res_cropped = $item['images']['standard_resolution']['url'];

// Regex Pattern        
$pattern = '#\/c+(.\d[0-9]+\.\d.)+(\d)#';

// Replace with empty string
$replacement = '';

// preg_replace
$full_res = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $full_res_cropped);
```

So the results are:

```
// $full_res_cropped cropped image URL (original)
scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s480x480/e35/c236.0.607.607/14474173_314142642294695_7071485231332589568_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=flarg

// $full_res resized, non-cropped URL (fixed)
scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s480x480/e35/14474173_314142642294695_7071485231332589568_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=flarg
```

This will work until Instagram changes the way that they crop and position the images and change the URL structure, but until then. Cool, I guess.

Hope this helps someone else having a similar issue!

Comment: Oh also, I found using http://www.regexpal.com/ was pretty helpful, but my regex statement probably could be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just check the box for non-square media in Client settings:
[image]

Comment: First thing I did, but it had no effect on the standard_resolution images in the JSON response.

Comment: many other people had same problem but were able to resolve in the end: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40347939/423089, i think for some the setting was reverted cause there was some info missing in the details tab and after fixing that, it was good

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following regexp:

```
'~/c\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,4}){3}/~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZT8vZo/3)

**Details**:

- `/`  - a slash
- `c` - a literal `c` char
- `\d{1,4}` - 1 to 4 digits
- `(?:\.\d{1,4}){3}` - 3 sequences of

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\d{1,4}` - 1 to 4 digits
- `/`  - a slash (if you remove it from the pattern, the regex may match a part of another URL subpart, but if you do, you will need to replace with an empty string)

[PHP demo](http://ideone.com/8Jfd9R):

```
$re = '~/c\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,4}){3}/~';
$str = 'scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s480x480/e35/c236.0.607.607/14474173_314142642294695_7071485231332589568_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=blah';
$result = preg_replace($re, '/', $str);
echo $result;
```